# Forward input to powershell, read output from it without the user seeing a console c#

Tags: c#, powershell

Is there any way I could have an application that acts as a different interface for a powershell prompt, like the ISE does? I just want to make it visually different. I'm thinking something to do with stdin and stdout, but i'm not totally sure how to make that work in C#. As well as the issue of hiding the console window.

Comment: You'll probably want to take a look at this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can use the PowerShell engine API to host PowerShell within a WPF or WindowsForms application.  See this [MSDN topic on hosting PowerShell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706563(v=vs.85).aspx) in your own application.